# Problemas con QT y MySQL Remoto

Tags: mysql, c++, qt

Tengo mi código funcionando en C++ y Qt 5.13.1 Mingw32
Mi código se conecta a Sqlite3 y una base de datos remota (todo dentro de la misma red)
Con sqlite3 no hay problema y hasta cierto punto con MySQL tampoco, el problema viene cuando intento registrar datos dentro de la tabla remota (de uno en uno) en ocasiones no registra todos los datos, a veces si, a veces menos. es raro el problema.
Ajunto el codigo que me esta dando problemas:

```
local->prepare("SELECT * FROM ProductosVendidos");
local->exec();
if( local->first() ){
    do{
        query->clear();
        query->prepare( "INSERT INTO ProductosVendidosR(Folio, Producto, Codigo, Cantidad, PrecioUnitario, Total, PrecioCompra, Terminal) "
"VALUES(:Folio, :Producto, :Codigo, :Cantidad, :PrecioUnitario, :Total, :PrecioCompra, :Terminal)" );
        query->bindValue( ":Folio", local->value(0).toString() );
        query->bindValue( ":Producto", local->value(1).toString() );
        query->bindValue( ":Codigo", local->value(2).toString() );
        query->bindValue( ":Cantidad", local->value(4).toString() );
        query->bindValue( ":PrecioUnitario", ceros( local->value(3).toString() ) );
        query->bindValue( ":Total", ceros( local->value(5).toString() ) );
        query->bindValue( ":PrecioCompra", ceros( local->value(6).toString() ) );
        query->bindValue( ":Terminal", myName );
        query->exec();
    }while( local->next() );
}
```

En donde local esta ligada a la sqlite3 y query a MySQL remota. Problemas de conexión no creo, ya que si conecta, el problema viene al querer registrar,  aveces registra 3 a veces 10 a veces 7 siempre en modo aleatorio y rara vez los 10 registros que tengo (hasta ahorita, por que siempre serán mas).
Todo esto esta dentro de un hilo que funciona bien y en segundo plano para no trabar la aplicación.

Comment: Me auto-corrijo El problema era simple: Uso Singleton para la conexión con la base de datos, por lo que creando solo la conexión remota desde el hilo de esta función; parece ser, que después de muchas pruebas el problema esta resuelto. Parece ser que conexiones creadas fuera del hilo que se usan dan problemas.

Answer (score 0):

`query->exec()` te devuelve un booleano que te permite saber si la sentencia SQL se ha ejecutado correctamente.

En vez de ignorar el resultado, deberías atenderlo y, en caso de encontrar un problema, mostrar el error y/o actuar en consecuencia:

```
if( !query->exec() )
{
  QSqlError error = query->lastError();
  qDebug() << error.text();
}
```

Comment: Si, había pensado en eso; pero imagina consultarlo mas de 100 veces por ciclo.
Encontré una forma que no se si sea la correcta:
db.setConnectOptions("MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT=1");
Esto en la configuración con la conexión a mysql, parece resolver el problema, ya que el error era que se desconectaba de la base de datos por alguna extraña razón.

Comment: @GeorgeCamelos consultar un booleano tras una consulta SQL es gratis, lo pesado es ejecutar el SQL y, a cambio, permites que tu código monitorice posibles errores. Una consulta SQL puede fallar por mil motivos... si no sabes qué ha pasado es complicado idear una respuesta

Comment: Después de intentar con setConnectOptions("MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT=1") sigue fallando y haciendo uso de el lastError() me arroja:
QSqlError("2013", "QMYSQL3: Unable to execute statement", "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
Que por lo que entiendo sigue perdiéndose la conexión con la base de datos.